Should "than," "like," and "as" be followed by "who" or "whom"?
Before anyone comments that "whom" is not necessary in the English language anymore and that I can just use "who" all the time instead, I'll say that my dialect always uses "whom" immediately after prepositions regardless of register. After words that can be used either as conjunctions or prepositions (such as the ones I listed above), I guess it can go either way? Neither feels more or less natural to me, so I'll have to defer to either prescriptive grammar or coin flipping on this one.
In my dialect, "than", "like", and "as" can be followed by either "me" or "I am." (never just "I," except for that one time I wrote "smarter than I" in a song.)
Edit: if the who/whom is not functioning as a subject or object in another subordinate clause. Example: "You said you're smarter than who/whom?" / ""You worry about people like who/whom?" / "You think you're not as smart as who/whom?"

Well, I was taught to say 'smarter than I am', so by that logic it should be 'smarter than who [is]?'

You need to provide examples because otherwise we are left with having to come up with examples (such as the prepositions and conjunctions you mention), which means more work for us. Also, you mention your dialect and fail to mention what dialect that is.

@Lambie I thought I already did provide examples in my post! I genuinely don't know how to classify my dialect but that's what I grew up saying, I guess (I'm from the United States so it's some type of American English dialect.)

@Lambie I know. I was saying that I have trouble identifying which dialect within the broader American English variant I speak.

@Lambie the thing, though, is that I actually think I speak a dialect. I don't think I speak general American English/"standard" American English given how obviously Asian-American my accent/pronunciation sounds. Which dialect I don't know, but I most likely speak a dialect of/in American English.

Does the fact that I'm a native (and not bilingual!) English speaker make a difference though? I assume the French and Russian people you mentioned are not native English speakers.

@Lambie maybe I speak standard English with a non-standard accent then. I do use "ain't" on occasion as well as "could" instead of "can," but not much else that's characteristic of non-standard dialects.

than => who
like => whom
as => who

Why is that the case though? / according to which source?

Actually I think I get it now. "Than" and "as" can be followed by "who is," but "like" cannot.

Usually "whom" ... but one can come up with counter-examples.
In general, the rule is that "who" is used for a subject and "whom" for an object. "Who is giving the present?", but, "You gave the present to whom?"
A preposition is normally followed by an object -- the object of the preposition. So "You are taller than whom?", "She looks like whom?", "He is as hungry as whom?" But a preposition can also be followed by a phrase, and in that case the word that is the subject of that phrase would be in the subjective case. Like, "She came before whom?", but "She came before who arrived?" "Who" is the subject of the phrase "who arrived", and so we say "who" rather than "whom".

'Whom' is rarely used nowadays except directly after prototypical prepositions. I'd say "He looks like whom?" is almost non-standard.

@EdwinAshworth Okay, in fairness I should have said, "by traditional rules of grammar". Yes, in common use, "whom" is fading away and many English speakers use "who" for both subject and object. I don't have statistics (and I'm not going to bother searching for any because I don't care!).

At what point do traditional rules of grammar become incorrect? When's the last time you said "It is I" or "It's we"?

@EdwinAshworth That's a discussion we've had on this site many times. At the one extreme are those who say, "Because this was written in a book 100 years ago, it's the rule and we all must follow it." At the other extreme is, "Rules of grammar are 'descriptive' and not 'prescriptive'. If people say it, then by definition it is correct." The problem with position A is that it ties us to old rules whose only authority is that they are old. The problem with position B is that it makes any discussion of "correct grammar" impossible. If someone said it, then by definition it's correct.

I'd say that 99+% of practised Anglophones wouldn't use "He looks like whom!?"

@EdwinAshworth Maybe not. But then, 99+% of Anglophones wouldn't use "Anglophones". They'd say, "English speakers". :-)

But seriously, for what it's worth, I ran a Google ngram on "to who" vs "to whom", https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+who%2Cto+whom&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 The result shows "to whom" declining sharply in popularity over time, but still well above "to who" even in the last year for which they have data, 2019, .00145 to .00015, over 9  to 1. "Like who" passes "like whom" around 1885.

I gave a different example ... and my first comment started " 'Whom' is rarely used nowadays except directly after prototypical prepositions."

To make it easy, consider that 'who' is to 'he' as 'whom' is to 'him'
So because:

we would say I am bigger than him, not I am bigger than he

therefore:

we should say I am bigger than whom?, not I am bigger than who?

Similarly:

we would say Like him

and so:

we should say Like whom?

And because:

we would say As big as him

that means:

we should say As big as whom?


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

That's exactly the problem! It's not easy because someone could say "he" or "him" in these cases, depending on whether they use "than," "like," and "as" as conjunctions or prepositions.

@Sophie I'd say they're not considering the conjunction/preposition debate when they do, just following the crowd/what sounds right.

"we would say I am bigger than him, not I am bigger than he"
This is just plain wrong. "I am bigger than he" is correct. It's an abbreviation of the original "I am bigger than he is big."
